# Change database column type to decimal

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

I am using Rails 3.2.3, and MySQL for my database

I have created a model affiliate_payment.rb, with a column `:amount`, initially with datatype `float`. I tried to change this to a decimal with the following migration:

```
class ChangeAffiliateIdAmountToDecimal < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :affiliate_payments, :amount, :decimal
  end

  def down
    change_column :affiliate_payments, :amount, :float
  end
end
```

Ran `rake db:migrate`...
 But when I check the column type to confirm, I find that the column type is now `integer`!

```
2.0.0-p353 :101 > AffiliatePayment.columns_hash["amount"].type
 => :integer
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
change_column :affiliate_payments, :amount, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

This will become [BigDecimal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this with new ruby syntax:

```
change_column :affiliate_payments, :amount, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey You have created the migration for change the column type so `rake db:migrate` need not be run.

You have to run the migration with there migration number like below

```
rake db:migrate:up VERSION = version number of migration.
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. The column type did change from float to integer, so the migration was run.

Comment: i am not getting you.