# How do i change column type from integer to decimal, with a letter after the decimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-6

I just realized my column type needs to be **decimal** instead of **integer**

Can i make the change directly in my seeds.rb or there's something else i should do?

Also how do i do this if i intend to add a letter after the decimal?

**Example:** `2.0L, 2.5L, 5.7L, etc.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change database column type to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699047/change-database-column-type-to-decimal)

Comment: It's still unclear to me but then i have made changes to the question so kindly read again.

Comment: Is the letter always "L"? I'm guessing this is L for liter? Can it sometimes be different such as "ml"? If it's always "L" there's no real reason to keep it in the DB. If it can change I'd recommend a second field called "unit_of_measure". Or better yet convert the value of your field to a standard unit of measure and possibly name the field accordingly (`displacement_liters`) now you know the number is always in liters. If you want to store less than a liter it would be `0.75` for 750ml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to store a letter in your DB, that column type can't be a decimal or integer. A string field would be more appropriate for your case. I'll assume your main question is regarding decimals though.

If you do want to change a column type in the DB, you're supposed to do it using [Migrations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). From terminal, in your app directory, run: `bin/rails g migration changeFieldNameFromIntegerToDecimal`.

This will generate a migration file with a timestamp in the filename, in which there is a change method telling rails how you want to change the database. In that change method, put:

```
def change
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :decimal, precision: :8, scale: :2
end
```

the precision and scale options do the follwing (from the above link):

> precision:  Defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing the total number of digits in the number.
>
> scale:  Defines the scale for the decimal fields, representing the number of digits after the decimal point.

If you want to convert it to a string, then the migration file would contain:

```
def change
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :string
end
```

Finally run `bin/rails db:migrate` from the terminal in your app directory to execute the migration.

Comment: Thanks but then i guess changing to string instead of decimal seems to be the best option?

Answer (score 1):

This will change the column type to decimal. To know about the scale and precision check out this Stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377176/12297707 or the docs https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers

```rb
change_column :table_name, :column_name, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2, :default => 0
```

Comment: Can you explain this?

Comment: this will change the column from integer to decimal try it.

Comment: It will change the column type to decimal, not matter it was an integer, to know about the scale and precision check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2377176/12297707

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it